# Need help in pattern printing

Tags: java

I need to print the following pattern and i almost did with the coding part.

```
1
1 2 1
1 2 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Following is the program I tried

```
public class MyPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7 - i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                int n = (int) Math.pow(2.0D, j);

                if (n > 100) {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                } else if (n > 10) {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                }

            }

            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int n = (int) Math.pow(2.0D, j);
                if (n > 100) {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                } else if (n > 10) {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + n);
                }

            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

When running the program I got the following output

```
        1
       1 2 1
      1 2 4 2 1
     1 2 4 8 4 2 1
    1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
   1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
  1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

But I need the output aligned to left (as specified first). Please help.

Comment: did you borrow the wrong code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's clearly caused by this part of code:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 7 - i; j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Have you tried running it without it?

Comment: Someone else posted this but for some reason deleted the answer

Comment: @user3002592 Don't forget to accept an answer you're happy with to close the question..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n > 100) {
    System.out.print(" " + n);
} else if (n > 10) {
    System.out.print(" " + n);
} else {
   System.out.print(" " + n);
}
```

Could also just be, as it does not matter what n is - it will all just do the same.

```
   System.out.print(" " + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment the line:

```
                //System.out.print(" ");
```

In the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you understand a few things.

```
// Make it ready for the loop, no point calling Math.pow() every loop - expensive
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class MyPattern {

    public void showTree(int treeDepth) {

        // Create local method fields, we try to avoid doing this in loops
        int depth = treeDepth;
        String result = "", sysOutput = "";

        // Look the depth of the tree
        for( int rowPosition = 0 ; rowPosition < depth ; rowPosition++ ) {
            // Reset the row result each time
            result = "";

            // Build up to the centre (Handle the unique centre value here)
            for( int columnPosition = 0 ; columnPosition <= rowPosition ; columnPosition++ )
                result += (int) pow(2, columnPosition) + " ";

            // Build up from after the centre (reason we -1 from the rowPosition)
            for ( int columnPosition = rowPosition - 1 ; columnPosition >= 0 ; columnPosition-- )
                result += (int) pow(2, columnPosition) + " ";

            // Add the row result to the main output string
            sysOutput += result.trim() + "\n";
        }

        // Output only once, much more efficient
        System.out.print( sysOutput );
    }

    // Good practice to put the main method at the end of the methods
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Good practice to Create Object of itself
        MyPattern test = new MyPattern();

        // Call method on object (very clear this way)
        test.showTree(5);
    }
}
```